# SQL Count Consecutive Days per line

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursive-query, sql-server-2017, gaps-and-islands

Looking to get the "Total Consecutive Days" per row.

Shift Table Contains ShiftId, ClientID, ServiceId and ProviderID
ShiftDetails Table has the dates.

There can be multiple Shifts with the same ShiftId, ClientID, ServiceId
There can even be duplicate dates.

Would like to have multiple "Total Consecutive Days" calculations.
Consecutive Days Per ClientID
Consecutive Days Per ClientID and ServiceID
Consecutive Days Per ClientID , ServiceID and ProviderID.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8861e5/1)

Answer (score 1):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  You can identify the islands by subtracting a sequence of integers from the date -- constant differences identify adjacent dates.  Then use `count(*)` as a window function:

```
select t.*,
       count(*) over (partition by clientid, serviceid, dateadd(day, -seqnum, date)) as consecutive_days
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by clientid, serviceid order by date) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
```

Comment: tried to convert it to my data. it's not returning the desired results. added query to question.

Comment: @monsey11 . . . Set up a db fiddle.

Comment: Here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8861e5/1 @/gordon-linoff